# Alternating jQuery functions on button click

Tags: jquery, function, button, alternating

I'm trying to get a button to alternate 2 functions, doing a different function on each click. This is the code I have:

```
var count = 0;
$("#pijlrechts").click(function() {
    count++;
    var isEven = function(someNumber) {
        return (someNumber % 2 === 0) ? true : false;
    };
    if (isEven(count) === false) {
        $firstFunction();
    } else if (isEven(count) === true) {
        $secondFunction();
    }   
});
```

It tells me the functions aren't defined, I made these functions earlier in the script.

Comment: Why `else if (isEven(count) === true)`? Is there a third state for a boolean?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from some *weird stuff* in your code, unless you have actually forgotten to define the functions the script complains about, there shouldn't be a problem.

**Correcting the *weird stuff*:**

1. The `isEven` function is completely redundant.
2. The expression `return condition ? true : false` is the same as `return condition`.
3. Since a boolean can either be `true` or `false`, there is no need for an `if...else if`. Simply check whether a condition is `true` (or `false`) and use `else` for the opposite case.

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var count = 0;

$("#pijlrechts").click(function() {
  /* Increment the counter. */
  count++;
  
  /* Execute the correct function based on the value of the counter. */
  count % 2 ? $firstFunction() : $secondFunction();
});

/* The functions your script complains about. */
function $firstFunction () { console.log("first") }
function $secondFunction () { console.log("second") }
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id = "pijlrechts">Click</button>
```

Comment: Deleting my answer in favor of this. Great answer.